# How do I insert primary id's from other tables into a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I have a table called "artist" with three columns:

```
artist_id {PK} | artist_name | artist_url
```

There are around 500+ artists in this table.

I want to be able to copy all of the primary keys over to a table called "artist_to_store". This table will have two columns:

```
artist_id {PK} | store_id.
```

Store ID will always be equal to 0

I thought this query would work:

```
INSERT INTO artist_to_store SET artist_id = (SELECT artistr_id FROM artist) AND store_id = 0
```

Instead it reuturns with the error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

I know what the error means so nobody needs to explain it. But could somebody please tell me how I get all of the artist_id's from the artist table to the other table?

Thanks,  and a Happy New Year when it arrives :)

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ::

```
INSERT INTO artist_to_store(artistId, storeId) SELECT artistr_id,0 FROM artist
```

Comment: where is the values keyword in insert query?

Comment: The author also should know about auto increment locking if uses InnoDB engine.

Comment: Igor Timoshenko: I didn't ask about incrementing, I asked about insert data from one table to the next. The increment is set to auto. it will increment in multiples of one. @Sashi Kant,  thank you, it works brilliantly. I will bookmrk this page :D :D

Comment: @raheelshan: VALUES is not needed when we insert from a select...
Peter : you are most welcome

Comment: @raheelshan: Thanks Raheel and a Very Happy New year

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO artist_to_store (SELECT artistr_id,0 FROM artist);
```

Try this

Comment: will that result, what the OP wants

Comment: Ha ha. @SashiKant happy new year buddy :) thanks for guiding :)

Comment: It was my pleasure Mate :-)

Comment: hmm thanks mate :) but guide me without down voting.. :P Are you from India?